# All App Engine Instances restarted on 25.12. and 31.12

Tags: google-app-engine

**Following situation:**

We have multiple GCP Projects using Google App Engine and in staging/production we do have a On-Prem-Varnish for caching in front of our instances.

Because of the Varnish we are only running a single instance of every App Engine Service which works totally fine regarding the load.

**This happened:**

On *25.12.2019 14:35 UTC* and *31.12.2019 21:45 UTC* **all of our App Engine instances** restarted at the same time which lead to a downtime of about 2-3 min.

For me it looks like the instances have been restarted by Google but I can't find any evidence for that, except for the dates and the fact, that all instances restarted at the same time.

**Question:**

If it was a Google thing (e.g. App Engine Update or something) can someone point me to the information resource?

If not: Could we have avoided this downtime if we had more than one instance running? I could imagine that if Google updates GAE, that they won't take down all instances of one service at a time.

**EDIT:**

The GAE instances are running on flexible environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess your GAE services are under the Flexible environment, in which case a weekly restart is expected and [documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-instances-are-managed).

These restarts are performed on a per-service basis. Since you mentioned all your services have only one instance, these restarts indeed cause a downtime during that time. Google recommends to have a least 2 instances of a service running to avoid these downtimes.

Comment: This seems to be a good point! Actually I forgot to mention, that they are running on flexible environment, I will add this to my Question.
Somehow I didn't realized those restarts before, I'll check this out.